# How do I deal with dynamic, parameterized, action spaces?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, deep-rl, q-learning, dqn

I want to design an AI Learning Algorithm for a Student made, round based Game.

Let me first explain the Game/Environment
You have a round based HTTP Game, in which multiple Players can participate.

Each player has the option within a round to:

- Buy new Robots (Or don't)

Additionally he has the option FOR EVERY ROBOT he owns to either:

1. **Mine** (If on a Planet that has a Resource)
2. **Regenerate** (Gives him Energy back, required for moving/attacking)
3. **Attack** (If Enemies are on the same planet, he can choose to attack a specific target, by providing the Id of the target.)
4. **Move** (LEFT,RIGHT,NORTH,SOUTH)
5. **Buy** one of the following ( Health Restore, Energy Restore, Mining Upgrade, MiningSpeed Upgrade, Storage Upgrade, MaxHealth Upgrade, Damage Upgrade, EnergyRegen Upgrade, MaxEnergy Upgrade )

So an example of an action within one Round could be, assuming Player A owns 2 Robots.

**1. Action**: [Buy 3 more Robots, Robot1: MoveLeft, Robot2: Mine]

in the next round it could look like this.

**2. Action**: [Robot1: Mine, Robot2: Mine, Robot3: MoveLeft, Robot4: Mine, Robot5: Buy Damage Upgrade]

To give a better overview, this is basically how a Map could look like.
[image: Picture of the Map]

As state I have:

1. Money a player owns
2. Positions and All Infos of EVERY Robot in the Game (Including Enemy Player Robots)
3. Everything there is to know about a Robot (e.g. Health, Upgrade Levels, current Resources in Inventory)
4. Positions of Planets (Including Resource amount, and which Robots are on it)

The Map has a fixed Size, but the amount of robots varies throughout the rounds played.

A next Round starts, once every Player has submitted a command for every Robot they own.

**The Goal?**
Make the most Money until the end of the game (you define a maximum amount of Rounds beforehands, e.g. 500)

**Question**
How can I possibly create an AI Player for this game?
Actions are dependent on one and another. For example if a player has 1000 Money, and he decides to spend all this Money on buying New Robots, then the actions for the robots he has, cannot include upgrading, because he used the money up already, so the action space depends on the previous actions chosen.

I know it is not a simple Environment but I would highly appreciate if someone could give me some hints about how to proceed with this.